# default value for date between

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I don't specify any date, I want to return all reservations.

I have a controller where a `RequestParam` is used:

```
public List<resrvation> getAll(@RequestParam(name = "date1",required = false)) String date1,@RequestParam(name = "date2",required = false)) String date2){
    return resrvationService.getAll( date1,date2);
}
```

My DAO:

```
Query("select DISTINCT  r from reservation  where r.dateRv between :date1 and :date2")
    public List<Reservation> getAll(@Param("date1") Date date1, @Param("date2") Date date2);
}
```

Comment: Put this logic into your service and then do e.g. a `findAll()`

Comment: I didnt get you ?

Comment: Use a different method to get all the value if you don't receive a date. Something like : `return date == null ? reservationService.getAll() . reservationService.getAll(date)`

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple, create two methods :

```
public List<Reservation> getAll():
public List<Reservation> getAll(Date, Date):
```

And in the controller, based on the parameter your received, call one or the other. Here is a simple example :

```
public List<reservation> getAll(
    @RequestParam(name = "date1", required = false) String date1,
    @RequestParam(name = "date2", required = false) String date2) {
    return (date1 == null && date2 == null) ? 
        reservationService.getAll() :
        reservationService.getAll(date1, date2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return all data if date is null then u can do something like this:
select DISTINCT  r from reservation  where
(:date1 is null or r.dateRv >= trunc(:date1 )) and
(:date2 is null or r.dateRv <= trunc(:date2))

use of trunc function is upto you

Comment: i have this exception Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'

Comment: date1 and date2 have data types Date or String ? date1 and date2 should have Date data type

Comment: pass param like @Param("date1") @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) Date date1

Comment: and date1 in info class will be as..  private Date date1;

Comment: the same thing :/

Comment: facing same issue of datatype conversion ?

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to answer your question without knowing what is your application technical stack is. If you are using Java8, You can also use optional for request parameters. Also try using spring-data-jpa derived queries on JPA repositories to get what you want.

```
public List<resrvation> getAll(@RequestParam(name = "date1",required = false)) Optional<String> startDate,@RequestParam(name = "date2",required = false)) Optional<String> date2){
if(date1.isPresent() && date2.isPresent()) {
   return reservationService.findAllBetweenStartDateAndEndDate( date1.get(),date2.get());
} else {
   return reservationService.findAll();
}
```

}

And On repositories

```
List<Reservation> findAll();
List<Reservation> findByDateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

Comment: I assumed your repository is JpaRepository i.e. spring-data-jpa, please refer here for the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: if you are not using JPA repository then you can write your own DAO methods for fetching between dates or fetching all the reservation records from the database